# Reverse proxy forward request via private IP?

Tags: networking, nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-ip

I have two EC2 instances, says EC2-a and EC2-b. EC2-a installed NGINX and served as reverse proxy, while EC2-b installed Weblogic which serve up my websites.

Since public-IP are not static, I'm wondering if EC2-a can forward requests to EC2-b via private IP?

Comment: Small note just to make sure you know you can set up static IP addresses for both of them, in case that's relevant to your use case.

Comment: @uprego: I'm thinking to serve EC2-a as reverse proxy, so I'll assign elastic IP to it. however since EC2-b is not public facing, and private IP is static, I was thinking to forward requests from EC2-a to EC2-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two instances need to be within the same VPC or share a security group.  Once you do, the private IP addresses are routable and you can set up your reverse proxy from there.